# jQuery .hide() and .show() applied to divs unnecessarily

Tags: jquery, html, css

I asked for help on the same project a couple weeks ago, and have just now come back to it (homework kept me from coding). Now i need help once more...

**Recap:** I'm making a sorting system to organize the anime i've watched/plan on watching. i've made the filters for the anime and all is good.

The problem i am having is when I go from one "filter" to another "filter" some divs are hidden and shown unnecessarily. I know where the problem is I just don't know how to fix it. Here is my jQuery

```
    $(".filters").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".anime").hide(500);
        $("." + $(this).attr("rel")).show(500); 
    });
```

The fault is in hiding anime div class... but if i don't do that, the anime divs that do not belong with a specific filter will remain. I'm new to jQuery so i don't really know what to do.

Here is a live preview of my code so far: http://swsthemelab.tumblr.com (i make it through tumblr because it's for my tumblr page. also, please don't click on the + that appear when you hover over the .anime divs, they haven't been customized.)

Comment: Try hiding only the ones you are not going to show: `$(".anime").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")).hide(500);`

Comment: I love you for putting Angel Beats…

Comment: Do you really need the animation? I don't think it would be a problem without animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cale suggested, you can hide the divs you do not need.

```
$(".anime").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")).hide(500);
```

Instead of

```
$(".anime").hide(500);
```

If you plan on filtering by categories ( Parent-child), I suggest you have a look at this plugin [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: The code filters by categories, but i will look into Isotope. Thank you.